# modify shell command in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox, I need to be able to read source code of shell
commands, and modify any command? any help please?
where i can find the shell commands? in which directory?

Comment: Ubuntu is open source. Add the source repositories and down-load any sources you want. Use the `type` command to find out where any given command resides. Add `-a` if you want to find every instance of a command.

Comment: The apt package manager will get you the source of any package on the system, and build it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Different shell commands will come from different places, however the following procedure is likely to work for a great many of them:

*(Note: You do **not** need to be root for any of this.)*

1. Figure out where the command file resides, e.g. to find `which`, try `type which` in your bash shell, or even `which which` (more generally, `which ...`, where `...` represents whatever command you wish to find).
2. Next, you'll want to see what package normally provides this.  `dpkg -S /path/name` can get you this, or, to combine steps 1 and 2: `dpkg -S $(which ...)`, e.g. `dpkg -S $(which which)`.  In this case, I get: `debianutils: /usr/bin/which`
3. Finally, you want to grab the actual source.  (Note: You may need to run `apt-get update` before doing this, especially if you get an error like `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`, which appears, at least in my case, to be a bit of a red-herring error message.)  This can be done with `apt-get source ...`, e.g. `apt-get source debianutils` (one could combine steps and do `apt-get source $(dpkg -S $(which which) | cut -d: -f1)`).

From there, you should have some new files and directories in whatever directory you started in (so start in an appropriate directory), containing the appropriate source.

Another example, in one-liner form:

```
cmd_to_get=ls; apt-get source $(dpkg -S $(which $cmd_to_get) | cut -d: -f1)
```

that grabs the source for `ls` (along with a bunch of other stuff that's in `coreutils` along with it).

From there, you can play around further.

If you'd like to then build things, see this [related question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get).

Happy hacking!